# Unable to unlist an R list

Tags: r, twitter

So I have a list of tweets that I obtained using the `searchTwitter()` function in R. Understandably, they are in a list. However, I'm unable to convert that list into a vector using the `unlist` function. `unlist(x)` gives me the same list `x`. I even tried with the `unlist(x, recursive = T)` option, it gave the same.

`dput(head(x))` gives

```
list(<S4 object of class structure("status", package = "twitteR")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("status", package = "twitteR")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("status", package = "twitteR")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("status", package = "twitteR")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("status", package = "twitteR")>, 
    <S4 object of class structure("status", package = "twitteR")>)
```

So the elements of the list aren't character strings, I suppose.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Could you show a small reproducible example using `dput`

Comment: you mean, `dput(x)`?

Comment: Yes, but only a subset of `x` i.e. `dput(head(x))` or so.  BTW, which package has this `searchTwitter()`

Comment: edited the question with the output. And it's the `twitteR` package.

Comment: okay, what does that mean?

Comment: It has specific methods for extraction.  BTW, even the `dput` from that is not reproducible.

Comment: so how do unlist a list like this? Any idea?

Comment: Can you check the `str(x)`  You may need some `@` etc.  I can't reproduce an example as it requires registered "OAuth"

Comment: Ah! Okay, so `x[[1]]$text` has the actual text. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

while you cannot unlist and get a vector, you could convert it into a dataframe first, `df <- twListToDF(tweets)`. and then use `df$text` to extract only the text into a vector. Hope this helps